# IntelliJ Update Frame Showing after every run or Debug web application

Tags: java, spring, web, intellij-idea

I am running **IntelliJ IDEA 14.0 ultimate 64 bit** .i started a spring mvc project from default template with jetty application server.
In Edit configuration i unchecked the Show Dialog every time i run/Debug the project .
[image]

But every time i run/Debug the project i see this annoying Dialog box
[image]

I their any way to stop this dialog every time i run/Debug project in intellij?

Comment: have you tried to clear the idea-project files/`.idea`-directory and setup the project once again?

Comment: JetBrains bugtracker at https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues is a more suitable place for reporting bugs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Settings *"On Update action"*, that you showed on screenshot will work only for Upadate project(`ctrl+f10`). For execute update you can press `ctrl+f10` or click on icon (blue circle arrow) on left toolbar of bottom panel.

[image]

In this case IDEA will work as specified in settings, and dialog will be not shown, if you disabled *"Show dialog"* checkbox.

Note, that IDEA will always show this dialog when you will try Run(`shift+f10`) or Debug(`shift+f9`) for application, which already running.

Restart and redeployment of project can take a lot of time. But when you want just update resources, or classes (without changes of interfaces), you don't need to restart project, because container (Thomcat, Jetty etc) can apply this changes "on fly". That's why IDEA offers you this options, for save your time, and make your work more convenient and effective.

So, to avoid showing of *"Update"* dialog you can:

1. Execute updating of the project (`ctrl+f10`), with disabled *"Show dialog"* checkbox.
2. Stop(`ctrl+f2`) current project running and Run(`shift+f9`) or
   Debug(`shift+f10`) it again.

Comment: Good idea to start from Deployment Panel on left side bar. but sill how to remove this frame from intellij as it supposed to be